# JSON CDL is omitting last row when parsing CSV with an empty last column

Tags: java, json, csv

I was playing with parsing CSV files into JSON using CDL library from org.json.CDL and I observed a strange behavior.

When I pass a CSV with an empty last value to the toJSONArray method, it's omitting the last row.

```java
package com.my.test;

import org.json.CDL;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CDLTest {
    @Test
    void testCDL_empty_column_fail() throws JSONException {
        final String SIMPLE_CSV_EMPTY_COLUMN_STRING = "Number,Name,Empty\n" +
                "1,Allice,\n" +
                "2,Chris,\n" +
                "3,Bob,";

        List<Object> jsonObjects = CDL.toJSONArray(SIMPLE_CSV_EMPTY_COLUMN_STRING).toList();

        assertAll(
                () -> assertNotNull(jsonObjects),
                () -> assertEquals(3, jsonObjects.size())
        );
    }

}
```

It's failing as well for that String:

```java
        final String SIMPLE_CSV_EMPTY_COLUMN_STRING = "Number,Name,Empty\n" +
                "1,Allice,not\n" +
                "2,Chris,empty\n" +
                "3,Bob,";
```

Do you have any idea how can I fix it? For learning purposes, I'd prefer to stick to this library and just fix it codewise. I was thinking about extending CDL and reimplementing method with a bug. Do you have any other idea, or maybe someone already fixed it?

Versions:
`<org.json.version>20190722</org.json.version>` and
Java 11

EDIT:
When I add a new line "\n" to the row `"3,Bob,\n";`, it parses correctly, but I think the assumption that CSV needs to end with a new line is wrong, is it?

The reason for this behavior is line 108 in CDL `rowToJSONArray` which assumes that the row needs something at the end:

```
            if (value == null ||
                    (ja.length() == 0 && value.length() == 0 && c != ',')) {
```

Comment: Based on https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt - "The last record in the file may or may not have an ending line break". So, the assumption required "\n" in the last line in your example is wrong.